# Action failed with "The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128"

Tags: github-actions

I am using github actions to publish a project to github pages, this is the yml file:

```
name: Pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main  # default branch

jobs:
  pages:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.REPO_TOKEN }}
          # If your repository depends on submodule, please see: https://github.com/actions/checkout
          submodules: false
      - name: Use Node.js 16.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16'
      - name: Cache NPM dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.REPO_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./public
```

when the steps run into `Deploy`, the github actions shows error:

```
Action failed with "The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128"
```

I am not sure should I use a organization token or use personal token? why this error happen? The log detail output look like this:

```
Run peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
[INFO] Usage https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages#readme
Dump inputs
Setup auth token
Prepare publishing assets
Setup Git config
Create a commit
Push the commit or tag
  /usr/bin/git push origin gh-pages
  remote: Permission to RedDwarfTech/blog.poemhub.top.git denied to jiangxiaoqiang.
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/RedDwarfTech/blog.poemhub.top.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
  Error: Action failed with "The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128"
```

this is the organization token access config:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[issue 742](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages/issues/742) of the [`peaceiris/actions-gh-pages`](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages) GitHub Action [mentions](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages/issues/742#issuecomment-1114440714):

> I had to change these settings under [Settings-Action-General](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#managing-github-actions-permissions-for-your-repository).
> Maybe worth calling out in docs:
>
> - Workflow Permissions: Rean (sic) and Write
> - Allow GitHub Actions to approve pull requests

---

And [issue 497](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages/issues/497#issuecomment-703025901) suggested:

> Fixed by recreating the API Deploy KEY.

Which lead to [PR 383](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages/pull/383/files) confirming:

> The generated `GITHUB_TOKEN` (github_token) does not support to push to an external repository.
> Use deploy_key or personal_token.

Comment: The first solution fixed the issue for me 